# How to change only the background alpha of TextView not the whole view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, textview

**N.B: This might be a duplicate post. But no previous solution worked for me...**

I'm trying to set TextView (only)background opacity from inside a RecyclerView Adapter(not both the textColor & background). Answer of previous question didn't worked for me.

***Output of Previous Suggestions***

> Case 1:

```java
holder.textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50, 0,255,0)); //this set alpha to whole view(both background + textColor).
```

> Case 2:

```java
holder.textView.setAlpha(50); //this also set alpha to whole view(both background + textColor).
```

> Case 3:

```java
holder.textView.getBackground().setAlpha(alpha); //NullPointerException
```

*Output*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference
```

**Here is my RecyclerView :**

```java
...
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        return new ViewHolder(textView);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setAlpha(50);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textView = (TextView) itemView;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            textView.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
            textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(6,24,1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP);
        }
    }

...
```

Comment: Case 3 is the way to do it, but if you're getting an NPE there, it means that the `TextView` has no background, so it's already transparent. If you do mean for it to have a translucent background, you need to supply a background first. `TextView` doesn't have one by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
....
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable();
         drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN); //Your color;
         drawable.getPaint().setAlpha(75); //BackGround Alpha between 0 to 100;
         holder.textView.setBackground(drawable);
    }
```